# How to prevent App Engine from merging multiple headers with the same name?

Tags: google-app-engine, http-headers

App Engine seems to always merge multiple headers with the same name into one. For example if one sets this in CGI

```
print "Set-Cookie: foo=bar"
print "Set-Cookie: spam=egg"
```

What is actually delivered to the browser is

```
Set-Cookie: foo=bar, spam=egg
```

which is of course wrong. The correct solution is either

```
Set-Cookie: foo=bar; spam=egg
```

or not merge them at all. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Is this in the SDK, or production?

Comment: It happens both in SDK and Appspot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe GAE is doing the correct thing, actually.  Multiple cookies are separated by commas, not semi-colons.  The semi-colon is used to separate parameters of a single cookie. I don't have time to look up the RFC link, but you can see examples all over the internet:

**CODE**

```
import httplib
c = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.facebook.com")

myHeaders = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    'User-agent': 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12",
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Keep-Alive': '300',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-us,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
}

c.request("GET", "/login.php", body="", headers=myHeaders)
r = c.getresponse()
print r.getheaders()
```

**RESULTS**

[ ... other headers snipped ...

('set-cookie', 'datr=5j9DTSaOPEd5Rxc9X23IB7KB; expires=Sun, 27-Jan-2013 22:15:02 GMT; path=/; domain=.facebook.com; httponly, lsd=0l0sd; path=/; domain=.facebook.com, reg_fb_gate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flogin.php; path=/; domain=.facebook.com, reg_fb_ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flogin.php; path=/; domain=.facebook.com')

]

Hope this is helpful
Ian

Comment: I checked the RFC and surprisingly it is indeed like what you described: comma to separate multiple cookies and semicolons to separater multiple parameters. My original question used some material which gets this completely wrong. 

Meanwhile, I think the comma is very problematic though: look at the "expires=Sun, 27-Jan-2013" part in the example you provided. This is such a great way to screw things up.

Comment: Indeed, the comma in that expires param is a source of much loathing.  With old-style "Netscape" cookies, multiple cookies came in as multiple "Set-Cookie" headers, and there was no problem.  Then someone came along with the idea that the cookies could all come on the same header, and in this case servers are supposed to either use the number-of-seconds-since-the-epoch-timestamp (like 1174098190.796) instead of that date-time string.. OR use double-quotes to surround that date-time string so the browser will understand what that comma is for.